# Why the following code does not throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, and print out 9 9 6?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to java. I had a doubt.

```
class ArrTest{ 
  public static void main(String args[])
{ 
    int   i = 0; 
    int[] a = {3,6}; 
    a[i] = i = 9; 
    System.out.println(i + " " + a[0] + " " + a[1]); // 9 9 6
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please note that, expressly because of the confusion you (and potentially someone else) are experiencing, it is *never* a good idea to try 'tricky' code like `a[i] = i = 9;`  Instead, factor it out to seperate lines - future generations will thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another good example the great Java evaluation rule applies.

Java resolves the addresses from left to right. `a[i]` which is the address of `a[0]`, then i which is the address of i, then assign 9 to i, then assign 9 to `a[0]`.

[`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) will never be throw since `a[0]` is *not out of bound*.
 The misconception is `a[9]`, which is against the **left-to-right-rule**

Answer (score 0):

It should not.

a[i] = i = 9  (makes i equal to 9)
a[0] should also be 9 since you assigned 9 to it (a[i] = i = 9), Initially a[0] was 3
and a[1] is 6 (initial value (int[] a = {3, 6};)

You should get 9 9 6.

If you do a[2] then it will give you an IndexOutOfBoundsException.